# Match a word, but ignore occurences in certain phrases

Tags: regex, splunk

I think I'm looking for a negative lookbehind regex, but I can't figure out the syntax.

I want to match a word in a single message field, but only when the word is not preceded by certain other words. The word *may* appear multiple times in the same message field -- as long as it's stand-alone somewhere, it should match.

Specifically, we have an alert to watch the logs for timeouts, and one of the match criteria is when the word "timeout" is part of the logged message. The trouble is that the message field also contains the stack trace, and the logs also contain many error events which are not timeouts. The stack trace often includes the word `timeout` as an argument to one or more methods for many different error conditions. These produce false positives (often, 50% of the alert results are not real timeouts). As arguments, they also specify the data type, such as `TimeSpan timeout` or `Int32 timeout` which is the type of multi-word "phrase" I'm trying to exclude/ignore.

These examples are slightly modified for simplicity.

An event that *should* match (the word "timeout" is stand-alone, even though it also exists as part of the unwanted "TimeSpan timeout" phrase later in the same message field):

```
Message: System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out. Increase the timeout value.
StackTrace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at ...(etc - many more lines of stacked calls)...
```

An example of log data that should *not* match, the word "timeout" doesn't exist stand-alone:

```
Message: System.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://xxxxx.
StackTrace:
at System.ServiceModel.Pool.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
at ...(etc)...
```

I thought this criteria would work, but it does not, it excludes *real* timeouts (like the first example) when those errors *also* have a stack trace with the `TimeSpan timeout` argument:

```
"timeout" NOT "TimeSpan timeout"
```

After I started thinking about regex, I tried a query along these lines but it appears to still match the `TimeSpan timeout` portions. I'm pretty new to Splunk and I've never used lookbehind regex so I suspect I just screwed up the details here. My thinking with the first "timeout" is to just quickly discard anything that doesn't mention "timeout" at all, then I thought the negative lookback regex would discard anything but events where "timeout" appears stand-alone:

```
index=foo "timed out" OR "timeout" | regex _raw="(?<!TimeSpan )timeout"
```

Edit: The regex by itself seems to be correct, see https://regex101.com/r/rZxkvm/1 ... so the problem is how I'm using it within a Splunk query.

(Please note I'm not interested in completely different criteria -- I realize in these examples I could search for something like `*TimeoutException` which is a common-enough naming pattern, but we have some systems for which the approach I've described is the only way to reliably identify real timeout errors and exclude false-positives.)

Comment: Looks like you need something like `^(?!.*TimeSpan timeout).*timeout`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that returns no matches at all -- bear in mind this is combined with a larger Splunk query, so even though Splunk claims their regex is perl-compatible, I'm uncertain whether it was a good idea to tag this with `regex`...

Comment: IME, Splunk doesn't do negative lookbehind/lookahead well, when it does it at all.  For better performance, use a positive-matching string.  Perhaps `[Tt]imeout[\s\S]+?StackTrace`.

Comment: @RichG thanks, I'll think about that angle. But it just occurred to me the alert _never_ cares about the content of the stack trace, so I can just grab the message substring up to that point and search on that instead. But I appreciate the idea.

Comment: If the alert doesn't need the stacktrace then, as you say, cut it out before looking for the keywords.

Comment: Give an example of when it *SHOULD* match - telling us when it *shouldn't* is not at all helpful, when you don't examples of when it *should*. There needs to be *GOOD QUALITY* sample data for you to get any kind of useful help :)

Comment: @warren The first example is clearly labeled "An event that should match" followed by an explanation of why, and the example itself. The issue is that the event includes _both_ desirable and undesirable matches. One that only matches would be trivial. Regardless, as noted above, I was able to resolve it by discarding the stack trace portion of the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to detect the word "timeout" in the message body then this would do it:

```
^Message:.*:.*\btimeout\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/ORmGIh/1/

Comment: I'm trying to detect the word "timeout" in the message body _but_ ignore any instance of "timeout" when it's preceded by certain other words (`Int32 timeout`) -- also in the message body.

Comment: @McGuireV10 You should add all relevant examples into a regex101 link. It will make things easier for both of us. Quite frankly, I'm not interested in deciphering details in a wall of text so TL;DR please.

Comment: Whatever. It happens to be a complex scenario. As noted in the regex101 link in the question, I believe the trouble is with the Splunk part of the query. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @McGuireV10 I'm not trying to be funny. Even Wiktor didn't bother to take notice of your `Int32` detail and he is the most detail-oriented person you could possibly hope to help you with regex.

Comment: @McGuireV10 Also, your regex syntax, Wiktor's, and mine can be seen at [splunk regex examples](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Regex#Examples) so at this time my best guess is that you're using splunk wrong or your data is not what you claim it to be.